# Разделение уровней доступа для пользователей сети.

Tags: linux, rsa, samba, openvpn

У меня значит такой, достаточно масштабный вопрос.

В данный момент такая ситуация:
Есть ubuntu сервер, к нему подключены через интерфейс eth1 несколько компьютеров (от 3 до 16 допустим). К интернету подключен через eth2. Так же есть openVPN'овский tap0 интерфейс через который подключаются другие компы (тоже допустим не более 16). tap0 и eth1 объединены в один интерфейс br0, так что есть одна локальная сеть с одним сервером (получается, пользователи OpenVPN и локалки отличаются только диапазоном адресов в одной сети). На сервере есть файловый сервер, принт-сервер, IPTV прокси-сервер и прочее.
Пользователи OpenVPN проверяются с использованием сертификатов со статическим ключом RSA.

Т.е. у меня есть несколько групп пользователей: пользователи локалки и несколько групп пользователей OpenVPN с разными сертификатами.

Задача:
Сделать для этих разных групп пользователей разные уровни доступа.
(Допустим, диск Store доступен для записи только пользователям локалки, для чтения доступен ещё группе Friends в OpenVPN, а IPTV только пользователям локалки опять же. Но, допустим, CVS сервер доступен всем группам кроме группы guests из OpenVPN)

Comment: Какие мысли в этом направлении:
Может быть создать линукс-пользователей для каждой группы и им выдавать права? Только тогда как-то нужно автоматически идентифицировать пользователя по его сертификату OpenVPN... а вот как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. У Вас есть определенная структура сети. В этой сети есть разные группы пользователей. Эти группы определяются по тому, как пользователи подключаются к сети. Например, пользователи локальной сети - это одна группа, а пользователи OpenVPN - это другая группа. Вам нужно, чтобы пользователи из разных групп имели разный доступ к приложениям сети. Например, CVS сервер открыт для всех, кроме пользователей-гостей. По сути, нужно создать группы, добавить в них пользователей и установить права доступа к приложениям для групп. Где возникает затруднение?

Comment: Если мы хотим, чтобы на CVS сервер заходили все кроме гостей, то почему нельзя создать группу cvs и добавить туда всех, кроме гостей?

Comment: Затруднение возникает в авторизации. Вот как подлючается пользователь openVPN к сети: он просто включает на компьютере соединение (логин и пароль вводить не нужно, идентификация по сертификату). С точки зрения сервера, это просто хост на таком-то интерфейсе. А мне нужно в соответствии с сертификатом пользователя убедить сервер, что это тот самый linux-user. Без входа в систему самими пользователям.

Comment: т.е. пользователь сам может даже не знать пароля от своего linux-user'а. Вот, например, в самбе, по-моему, есть какая-то "машинная" авторизация. Не смотрел внимательно про это, но суть в том, что сервер узнаёт пользователя по его машине

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть настройки брэндмауэра: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#policy

Answer (score 1):

Поискал по интернетам информацию, и что-то мне уже кажется, что единственный вариант - настроить для каждой группы свой ip-диапазон, так как другой альтернативы OpenVPN не предусматривает:

> Можно попробовать посмотреть настройки брэндмауэра:
>
> http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#policy

(Изначально я хотел, чтобы по сертификатам пользователя после авторизации в OpenVPN проходило что-то вроде авторизации в системе)

Тогда получается что для каждой программы, где это предусмотрено указывать правила доступа отдельно, правильно? Или есть более красивый/удобный подход? (Например в самбе нужно, чтобы какая-то группа имела доступ, но только на чтение, поэтому просто обрубать соединения фаерволлом не прёт)

Comment: Возможно, помогут списки контроля доступа: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/access_control_list